# Point web root to a specific file in IIS

Tags: php, windows, iis

I have an application which I wrote and I need to force all the web traffic through this file. 
so even if they go to route `site.com/param1/param2/param3` the traffic will be going through the following URL: `site.com/index.php/param1/param2/param3`

On Linux, this is easy just by setting the entry point in apache straight to the file. 
But I can't find a way to do this in IIS on windows server.

How do I do this?

Comment: Its like Linux `.htaccess`. https://superuser.com/questions/800261/using-htaccess-with-iis

Comment: so what would I have to add to that file to make it point to my index.php? And I can see there is a lot of stuff in this file that is coming from the IIS its self, If I update it in this file will it update the IIS system interface also or will IIS overwrite my changes?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use IIS url rewrite to achieve your requirement.

You could install it by using IIS web platform installer. Details you could refer to this link.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Then I suggest you could try to add below url rewrite rule into the IIS web application's web.config.

```
            <rule name="aaa" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/index.php/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
```

---

You could add a condition to check the url is match example.com/index.php, if match not redirect again.

```
            <rule name="aaa" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/index.php/{R:0}" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com/index.php" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
```

Comment: thank you. I'll be working on the project again tomorrow so I'll try it then and let you know the feed back

Comment: this results in an infinite redirect loop

Comment: You could add a condition to check the url is match example.com/index.php, if match not redirect again. Details see the update.

Comment: but technically this is just a redirect correct? im actually wanting something that will tell the root directory to always redirect all traffic through index.php without having to physically show that in the url. like i said with linux this is easy because all i do is set the docroot to /path/index.php and then even if i type in example.com/something its actually going through example.com/index.php/something

Comment: if i just did a redirect to example.com/something it would give me a 404 as there is nothing there other than the index.php and all the code in that file which would then process the trailing URL string